# Webform Title Issue

Tags: forms

I'm using Drupal 8 and the Webform module. I have entered a title for my form, but when you view the form the title defaults to "Main page content." I have three forms, including the default Contact form and all of them have this as a title. The correct title does display in the webform admin pages.

Thanks,

Kateva

Comment: I don't think your description is clear enough

Answer (score 0):

Mmmm when you installed webform is this a fresh site, or did you upgrade "yaml form" - to webform, if so might be a halfbaked migration.

can you replicate this with a fresh Drupal install and webform install ?